# How to modify a character in a string with null

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am making an assembly language program which takes as input a string and two indexes
and removes the substring between these two indexes
The approach I am using is to increment the offset to the last index and then print edx
This will print second half of the string. Now to print the first half I am thinking of 
putting the NULL character at the startIndex of the string 
Is there some way to do it ? or a better alternative ?

```
include irvine32.inc

.data
testString byte "Print it",0
enterString byte "Enter a string : ",0
startString byte "Start Index : ",0
endString byte "End Index : ",0
subString byte "Substring : ",0
stringEntered byte ?
startIndex dword ?
endIndex dword ?
enteredString byte 101 dup(0)
enteredStringCopy byte ?
byteCount dword ?
source BYTE "AABCDEFGAABCDFG",0 ; size = 15
target BYTE 100 dup(0)

.code
main PROC
; print msg to enter a string
mov edx, offset enterString
call writestring

; read the string into stringEntered variable
mov edx,OFFSET enteredString ; point to the buffer
mov ecx,SIZEOF enteredString ; specify max characters
call ReadString

mov byteCount, eax
; so we have read the string into stringEntered variable
; This variable points to the memory location where the string is
; stored The last mov instruction stores the number of bytes
; into the variable bytecount

; print msg to enter the start index
mov edx, offset startString
call writestring
call readint
mov startIndex,eax
; store the start index in startIndex variable

mov edx, offset endString
call writestring
call readint
mov endIndex, eax
; store the endIndex into endIndex variable


;INVOKE Str_copy,  ADDR enteredString, ADDR enteredStringCopy


; put the terminating character at index startIndex - 1
; then print the enteredString that will print the
; characters from 0 to startIndex - 1

mov edx, offset enteredString
add edx, startIndex
mov ebx, null
mov [edx],ebx
call WriteString
call crlf


mov edx, offset enteredString
add edx, endIndex
call WriteString

exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Yup, slap a `0` byte (ASCII NUL, not NULL) into the string will truncate the string to just the first part.  And yes, you can print the tail of a string by passing a pointer to any starting-point you want; that's how implicit-length C strings work.  If you can modify the string and can do 2 separate prints, that's a very easy way.

Comment: I have pasted the code above I am doing it like `mov ebx, null` but that doesn't work. I am not sure what u mean by ascii null.

Comment: See http://www.asciitable.com/ for names of ASCII control codes.  It's just a `0` byte, or `'\0'` if you want to write it as a character constant.  `mov byte ptr [edx], 0`.  (Not a dword store of a register, that would overwrite 4 bytes).  You don't want `null` to appear in your source code anywhere; "null-terminated string" is using the English word "null" to describe a `0` byte, in contrast to a NULL-terminated linked list, where *in C* (not assembly), `NULL` is the name of a pointer constant.  If you're not talking about pointers, don't capitalize null, and preferably don't use it at all.

Comment: Thanks that worked. If you could help me with one more minor thing it would be great. Like if I have to mov a string to edx we normally do `mov edx, offset subString` Is it possible that instead of declaring this variable subString in the .data section I specify the string directly in the mov instruction ?

Comment: No, everything on the line of the `mov` instruction will assemble into bytes in the code section.  If you want `mov edx, pointer to "hello world"` to magically create a string constant somewhere else as well as assemble the mov-immediate instruction bytes, you need to either write a macro, or use a different language.  (e.g. C, where you have a *compiler* not an *assembler*).  In asm, if you want something in memory somewhere, you have to put it there, separately from things that reference it.